# find all triplets $(a,b,c)$ such that $ab+bc+ca=1$ and $a^2b+c=b^2c+a=c^2a+b$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, contest-math, real-numbers

Given that $a,b,c \in R$ find all triplets $(a,b,c)$ such that $ab+bc+ca=1$ and $a^2b+c=b^2c+a=c^2a+b$.

Attempt:

Case $I:$ Exactly one of $a,b,c$ is zero. WLOG, let $a=0$. Then we have
$$bc=1$$ and
$$c=b^2c=b$$
Solving we get
$$b=c=\pm 1$$
By the same symmetry we get $6$ triplets viz. $(1,1,0),(-1,-1,0),(1,0,1),(-1,0,-1),(0,1,1),(0,-1,-1)$

Case $II:$ None of $a,b,c $ is Zero.
Let us assume:
$$a^2b+c=b^2c+a=c^2a+b=p$$
Then we have:
$$a^2b^2+bc=bp$$
$$b^2c^2+ac=cp$$
$$c^2a^2+ab=ap$$
By adding all the above equations and
Using the fact that:
$$a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2=(ab+bc+ca)^2-2abc(a+b+c)=1-2bac(a+b+c)$$

We get
$$2-2abc(a+b+c)=p(a+b+c)$$

$\textbf{ANY HINT PLZ}$

EDIT:
Case $III:$

If $a=b=c \ne 0$ Then we get two more triplets.
$$\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right),\left(\frac{-1}{\sqrt{3}}, \frac{-1}{\sqrt{3}}, \frac{-1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The case $a,b,c \neq 0 \implies  c = \dfrac{a(1-ab)}{1-b^2}= \dfrac{ac(a+b)}{1-b^2}\implies a^2+ab=1-b^2\implies a^2+ab+b^2 = 1$. Thus it follows that: $b^2+bc+c^2 = 1 = c^2+ac+a^2\implies a^2+b^2+c^2 = 1$. But Cauchy-Schwarz inequality says: $1 = a^2+b^2+c^2 \ge ab + bc + ac = 1$. So $a = b = c = \pm \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$, and this is the only solutions for this case. The other cases are treated already.

Comment: For cleanliness, avoid dividing by $1 - b^2$, which could have been 0. Just write the first line as $ c (1-b^2) = a ( 1 -ab) = ac (a+b) $.

Comment: Actually when $b=\pm1$, it boils down to $a=b=\pm1$ which contradicts the hypotheses $a \ne b \ne c \ne 0$. So its trivial that $1-b ^2 \ne 0$

Comment: @EkaveeraGouribhatla: if $b = \pm 1 \implies a = \pm 1, c = \pm 1,0$, and this contradicts some of the given equation or the condition that $c \neq 0$.  Also, by the notation $a,b,c \neq 0$ I mean $a \neq 0, b \neq 0, c \neq 0$.